# Calling multiple numbers, and connecting to both via browser

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I am using the Twilio JS quickstart, along with a custom Python backend.

I am able to initiate two calls via the backend, and return the unique call SIDs to the JS frontend.

Is there any way for me to - given only those callSIDs - join into those calls via my browser? I'd like to be able to join (i.e attach my Twilio.Device() to the call) one, and leave it to join the other, potentially multiple times while the calls are inflight. However, I only want / need a single *active* connection with a call and my Twilio device at any given time.

I have seen the "" and multiple  verbs, but those seem to cancel the other phone calls as soon as someone picks up the phone.

Twilio.Device.connect(callSid) would be an ideal API, but curious to know if this is even possible.